# QGIS - Coodinates

Tags: mapping, coordinates, qgis, coordinate-systems

I am trying to map some habitat sites in Devon, I created coordinate points from when I was in the field (e.g. 50530384, -4.230573). When I go to map these in QGIS, using the OS standard map, the points are either completely off the map or they are about 10 miles north of where they are meant to be.

When I look at the coordinates QGIS is giving along the bottom, it is more like 6539061, -470779, which is quite different to my coordinates. However if I use these coordinates instead it still doesn't fix the issue.

I have checked the CRS multiple times, and tried changing it. It auto sets to WGS 84 / Pseudo Mercator (normally I would set it to WGS84, but when I set it to this it deleted my map entirely).

Any other fixes?? I think my coordinates are right and it is an issue with the map but I simply cannot figure it out.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Note: CRS should be set for every layer (and not just for the project). And your questions is not about programming. We have a sister site about gis (gis.stackexchange.com), which may be more relevant (but you should add which coordinate systems are you using). And my tip: start with country boundary layer (one which has already set a CRS on the data), and then add other layers. It helps to debug where the error is.